# Open my app when user says app name in google now or google assistant

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk, google-now

I want to open app name "myapp" when user searches or says "myapp" in google now or google assistant. not "start myapp" or "open myapp"... just "myapp". The app is a specific activity that has been installed.
Try saying ok google amazon or uber or whatsapp.. it directly opens the app. Is there a way to implement the same for my app???

Comment: If your app an Android app or an Action?

Comment: i made an android app, try saying ok google.. amazon or whatsapp or uber or facebook, it directly takes us to the app. is there a way to implement it for my app too?

Answer (score 0):

The Google assistant do it automatically, i already tried it. You don't need to modify anything in your app.

Comment: In my case it is not opening the app. My app is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.infinite.cosmos and my voice command is "Open Snaps: Memories and Thoughts" is not opening my app. While giving voice command "Open Diary, Journal, Notes, Mood Tracker- Snaps Journal" showing the app but not launching it